# How to search using material ui auto-complete?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, event-handling, material-ui

I'm looking for an alternative for material-ui-search-bar since it's not maintained. I was recommended to use material ui's auto complete. However, in the examples that I have seen, I can only see text-fields like structures where we can type. Then there's a cross button when we are typing.

Is it possible to have a search button or something within this auto complete field where I can use an event handler too? I want to hit the search button within this field & call an event handler once I am done typing.

Code Sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/d07uv?file=/demo.js

Comment: You want to call an event handler and get the selected input value to the function right?

Comment: Yes, I want to run graphql queries on the basis of the input @DushanRandika

Comment: Nice. I just made a sandbox solution for that. You can get the selected film name and the index in case if you need.

Answer (score 0):

Yes of course, that is possible. As you have mentioned I have added an event handler for your first text field. For that I am using a search button. Once your searching and the film selecting is done you can click the search button. Then the event handler is called and you can see the selected film name and it's index in the event handling function(Look at the console). Hope that would help :)

Here is the sandbox link:
https://codesandbox.io/s/a125-material-ui-search-fhgd6

Comment: Maybe I am understanding it incorrectly. What I wanted is to type something in the search bar and then run a query using what I typed. But in your example, I can only select from the dropdown menu, right? I tried to add a value to store what I am typing in the text field. dk why it didn't work. Is it possible to remove the drop down menu? If I remove options, it doesn't work.  https://codesandbox.io/s/a125-material-ui-search-2u98k?file=/demo.js

Comment: Actually, I could just use the text-field I guess

Comment: Yeah that is possible. I thought use just wanted to search and select and item from the dropdown. Let me edit the solution. Yes men. For that purpose, using the text field is just enough. You don't need to select something from a dropdown right.

Comment: Here is the new link check this out. https://codesandbox.io/s/strange-proskuriakova-lu90u

Comment: So, does this mean it's not possible to use auto-complete without the dropdown menu?